# Сравнение строки декодированной из base64

Tags: python, base64, compare

Почему две одинаковые строки не одинаковы, как правильно их сравнить?

```
import base64

b64 = 'AAAAAFN0YWtlIDE4NS4yMDAwMDAwMDAgYWNjZXB0ZWQ=\n'
msg = 'Stake 185.200000000 accepted'

base64_bytes = b64.encode('utf-8')
decode_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_bytes)
decode = decode_bytes.decode('utf-8')

print(decode)       #Stake 185.200000000 accepted
print(msg)          #Stake 185.200000000 accepted
print(decode==msg)  #False
```

Comment: А почему вы решили что они одинаковые? decode на четыри символа больше msg

Comment: На 5 если точно :)

Comment: `print(repr(decode)); print(repr(msg))`

Comment: @Владимир Клыков пучарме визуaльно видно четыре :)

Comment: Кавычка в конце строки еще кроме первых четырех

Comment: @Владимир Клыков  print(len(decode)-len(msg))  ответ 4

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/6acd4

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Ваши аргументы очень убедительные :)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за наводку, в терминале строки выглядели одинаково.
Решил проблему, удалив нулевые символы функцией strip()

```
import base64

b64 = 'AAAAAFN0YWtlIDE4NS4yMDAwMDAwMDAgYWNjZXB0ZWQ=\n'
msg = 'Stake 185.200000000 accepted'

base64_bytes = b64.encode('utf-8')
decode_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_bytes)
decode = decode_bytes.decode('utf-8').strip().strip('\x00')

print(repr(decode)); print(repr(msg))
print(decode==msg)
```